The problem is that the entire page reloads when browsing the sites
On StackExchange sites, if I'm browsing, for example, I click on Questions, or I search for something, the problem is that everything reloads.
If I, for example, click on the inbox menu, the whole page doesn't reload to see what messages I'm getting, that seems fine to me, but it should be like that for more parts of the site.
Like on YouTube, if I change the video, only the important things change, which is the video, the title, the comments, not the page reloading.
This reloading of the page causes the browser to turn the entire background color, which in my case is gray, making it so that if the background is white, it goes to gray and the white background is visible again.
I find it a bit annoying.
On Android 5 with Opera beta I don't have that problem, only on the computer with the browser I use, which is Vivaldi 5.2.2623.18 (Stable channel) stable (64 bits),  https://vivaldi.com/en/download/archive/?platform=linux, if possible I will update the browser later.

I want to tell you that when I posted this question, I didn't realize that the problem was because I was using an old browser. I'm in a really difficult economic situation. A few days ago my power cable burned out and I almost lost my computer. Now I'm using a 2006 one with Linux. Because of the current situation, I can't buy a new cell phone because it costs like 300 euros, and neither my Android nor my PC have free space. I only have a 14 GB disk with basic programs to make it work, and with luck sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. For this reason I can't keep the browser updated. If someone is going through a similar situation, you might understand me, but since everyone is using the latest versions of everything because they're up to date with the latest technology, I find it unlikely that they'll understand me.

Yeah, the internet can be annoying. But seriously, loading pages is one the most basic things in web. There are sites that preload stuff, using frames, and other tricks, but it's surely not the standard and has lots of downsides as well. FYI, the company blog is using such technique.

This isn't a bug. It's the way the sit is designed. Assuming you're asking for a change, which this really isn't written as (it's written as primarily a complaint), then it's a feature request. Given that what you're asking for is a complete redesign of the underlying mechanism that the site uses for paging, potentially requiring ditching substantial/most of the existing code, I consider it highly unlikely that this will be implemented in the near-term, if ever.

That doesn't mean there aren't areas where it would be reasonable for updates to be dynamically loaded into the page, rather than refreshing the page or opening a new page. However, it's substantially more work to make sure you update everything that needs updating, rather than forcing a reload.

@Makyen looks like the main concern is the questions, i.e. when in homepage or questions list (e.g. search) instead of reloading the whole page, "just" load the question you click. Kind of like how the blog is working.

@ShadowWizard To me, that appears to just be an example, as explicitly stated by the OP in the question.

If there is one thing I like about Stack Exchange, it's that it is not full of bloated JavaScript reimplementing basic browser functionality.

What is the actual problem here? Why does this feature request improve things? If we go by "I find it a bit annoying", I can probably create about a hundered FRs just off the top of my head. I haven't because I don't think it's worth my time to do that, nor do I think it's really worth addressing each one individually. Many things I live with or avoid or write a quick userscript for. I only create FRs for things I think are going to benefit more than just my annoyance. So, why do you think this change would be a benefit to me and/or other people who aren't you?

I live in the middle of the Amazon rainforest, I'm Blanka's neighbor, if I go out in the street I risk being arrowed, if I go into the yard I risk being eaten by a jaguar. For me at last, I don't think a few page reloads is a top priority.

@VLAZ Aside from the issue of changing the background color, this could serve to reduce bandwidth and waiting time for the site to load.

Bandwidth, not really. It would just change when the site loads - the same amount of loading needs to happen either way. Depending on implementation, it might increase bandwidth usage by preloading pages you never look at.

As for waiting time - I mean, sure, but how long are you waiting? If it’s less than a couple seconds per page, I just can’t see that being worthy of a full redesign and all the bloat that would have to come with it. Even a minute or more would be stretching it, to say the least.

@Anerdw I think the faster the loading the better, if I multiply the waiting time of a person by the number of users, it will surely be a long time.

I recommend you read the entirety of this series of posts by Nick Craver, former grand-high-poobah-of-making-Stacks-run-good and consider how much work has already gone into making SE work as well as it goes, especially noting the near-obsessive dedication given to page-loads. Then, when you're convinced you have a way to load Stack pages better, write it up as a full-fledged [tag:feature-request]. (Sorry, Nick, for not knowing your actual title.)

"fast loading" is not an intrinsic property of in-page loading applications. Nor is the lack of colour change. These are both things you have to add yourself when making an in-page loading app. Browsers have had 30+ years to optimise the experience of each page hit being a new GET for the entire document and its resources. Doing it yourself with HTTP calls looks like it'd be less bandwidth but should be the same if you factor out cached resources. But that approach also adds complexity and way harder to deal with state. Consider having to unload event listeners when you swap out content.

Yes, that's not hard by itself but there is so much more, as well. It takes a lot of time and effort to turn it into smooth experience. Unlike with an HTML document where you basically get it for free. That's not to say it's not possible - YouTube does the in-page loading, as pointed out. But also YouTube has a lot of time and effort available.

Bottom line is that what you describe as "in-page" loading does not do what you ascribe to it. You should be really careful what you ask for. If you find loading times are bad, that might not be fixed by in-page loading.

Turns out that your problem got nothing with the bug/request you're asking here. It's because you are using a browser that is not supported by Stack Exchange.

"We support the last two stable versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use. This does not include beta, developer, nightly, canary, or any other pre-release versions of browsers, which are not supported." - Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need? - Meta Stack Exchange. See also: https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/

From the question,

Vivaldi 5.2.2623.18 (Stable channel) stable (64 bits), https://vivaldi.com/en/download/archive/?platform=linux

As a feature-request, I'm afraid this will not be accepted by Stack Overflow's developers because Vivaldi is not a supported web browser, and Vivaldi version 5 is too old, as Vivaldi's current version is 7.
I suggest you to update your web browser. If you still have problems, then make a new post, but this time use support.
References

Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?


Addendum
From https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/
Desktop browsers
Chrome 131
Chrome 130
Edge 131
Edge 130
Firefox 133
Firefox 132
Opera 114
Opera 113
Safari 18.1
Safari 18.0
Mobile browsers
Chrome for Android 131
Safari on iOS 18.1
Safari on iOS 18.0

I don't think you understand what the browser support is for - it's for bugs and for general feature support, i.e. how modern the HTML/CSS/JS language features are. It doesn't prevent raising feature requests that would apply to any browser on account of the requester using an old browser.

Thanks for the reply, we both speak Spanish, but I reply in English on these sites (if there's any bad detail it's because of Google Translate), if you look at the revision history, I actually reported it as a bug, but it was modified... As they say in the comments, the SE blog does have partial loading, which I think is great, I suspect they're busy with more important things, but it would be nice if they would revamp the whole site. What I would like is that the first time you enter it does load everything, but once inside the site it loads only what is necessary.

@ArtEze It's better to keep the comments in English. If you like, we can chat in Spanish. I made a couple of mistakes when I created a chatroom, so I deleted it and created a new one. Let me know if you have problems finding the second chatroom (I pinged you, so I expect that you get a notification).
